# Importing module from Github to use in Python

Tags: python, github, python-module

I'm a beginner in Python and I have no experience with GitHub at all. I want to import the module `semsimlib` from the following URL: https://github.com/timvdc/semsimlib

I have looked on the internet for help on how to do this but most of it is very unclear and doesn't seem to work for me. Can anyone provide a detailed explanation on how to do this in a easy way?

Comment: Show what you tried. This is not a tutorial site. If you can't understand a tutorial, it's likely that you won't be able to understand the answers posted here either, unless you can articulate exactly what it is you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the repo does not provide appropriate scripts to simply install the package. There is no `setup.py` file and there is no distribution on pypi.

What you can do is go to `site-packages` folder inside your python installation or inside your virtual environment. Then run `git clone https://github.com/timvdc/semsimlib`. You should now be able to import `semsimlib`. Keep in mind that you will also have to install all the other dependencies your self one by one since there is also no `requirements` file.

You can also clone the repo into any folder on your computer and at the top of your script put:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/semsimlib/folder")
```

`semsimlib` will now be importable. However, I would try to get it to work with the first method.

Comment: what do you mean by virtual environment?

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk) tutorial. If you do know what virtual environment is that means all your packages are installed globally. You need to look for `site-packages` folder inside your python installation on your machine.

Comment: Okay, so when i type in `git clone https://github.com/timvdc/semsimlib` I get the following message: `fatal: destination path 'semsimlib' already exists and is not an empty directory.'` Now, when I try to run some example code by importing semsimlib it still says "module semsimlib not found".